# Karma and Jasmine - Testing jQuery ajax promise

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-jquery, karma-jasmine

I am writing some tests for a rest api in karma/jasmine and I am using the $.ajax() method from jquery.

$.ajax returns a promise. How to handle this in testing?

To test the success of a request, I could do this:

```
var promise = $.ajax(...)
promise.done(function(data){
    expect(data).toBe( ... );
});
```

But how do handle failures?

```
promise.fail(function(){
    // ????
});
```

I mean, can I "Throw" an error in this case or something like that?

Comment: Have you got the solution?